# Asp.Net: send SignalR message on Application_End

Tags: asp.net, signalr, exit, signalr-hub

I have a standard Web Forms application that includes a SignalR hub for JavaScript clients. The hub itself works fine and messages are being sent and received as expected.

When the application is terminated (usually via application pool recycling), I want to send a specific message to all connected SignalR clients.
So I hooked into Global.asax's Application_End like this:

```
void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            var hubNotifyTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                 IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SiteMasterJsClientHub>();
                 context.Clients.Group("Group with all users").OnServerStartup("any message");
            });
}
```

Well...this doesn't work. If i put the code outside of Application_End, it works and the clients receive the message.
My guess is that SignalR auto-detects the application shutdown and terminates all connections. I haven't found any documentation to verify that though.

So my question is: how can I send an automatic SignalR message just before the application shuts down?

Comment: Have you added RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(); to your Application_Start?

Comment: My routing config looks different; but the hub in general works. I am using if for other things where it works fine. Just the application end message doesnt work.

Comment: Okay then try this method sendNotificationWeekly() in `camelCasing`.

Comment: Please share your method `OnServerStartup` in hub class `SiteMasterJsClientHub`

Comment: As I have said before: the code works outside of Application_End. I can call OnServerStartup  manually and the client will receive the message and execute the code for it.

Comment: I guess the hubs are closed before control reaches to `Application_End`

Comment: Thats also my assumption..so my question is: how can I send an automatic SignalR message just before the application shuts down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try `IRegisteredObject` present in System.Web.Hosting namespace.

First we create an object that implements `IRegisteredObject` interface and register it with ASP.NET hosting environment by calling `HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject`. With that in place when the app domain is about to unloaded, the ASP.NET hosting environment will call the `Stop` method implementation of `IRegisteredObject`.

Create a class `TerminationCommand` which implements `IRegisteredObject`

```
public class TerminationCommand : IRegisteredObject
{
    private readonly IHubContext siteMasterJsClientHub;
    public TerminationCommand()
    {
        siteMasterJsClientHub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SiteMasterJsClientHub>();
    }

    public void Stop(bool immediate)
    {
        siteMasterJsClientHub.Clients.Group("Group with all users").OnServerStartup("any message");
        HostingEnvironment.UnregisterObject(this);
    }
}
```

Next we need to register our `TerminationCommand` class in `Application_Start` section

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    //Existing code.
    HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(new TerminationCommand());
}
```

**References**

[IRegisteredObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.iregisteredobject?view=netframework-4.8)

[HostingEnvironment.Registered method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.registerobject?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Hi and thanks for the idea. This does not completely solve the problem, as the hub still might shut down before all clients get the message, but at least it works in some instances. I'll accept your answer as it was helpful.